# Source of image frm string using pattern matching PHP

Tags: php, css

I have in a variable $var = 'src="some-http-source" ' i want to get the value inside the inverts as a variable using pattern matching in php please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = 'src="some-http-source"';
$matched = array();
preg_match('@src="(.+)"@', $var, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // there it is!
```